# Case When Evaluation Order

Tags: sql, if-statement, case-when

I have a Case When statement in SQL with multiple conditions and I need the conditions to be evaluated in the correct order.
This is my code.

```
SELECT company_id, 
MIN(CASE WHEN number_of_orders >= 10 THEN order_month 
WHEN number_of_orders >= 1 AND number_of_orders < 10 THEN order_month 
ELSE NULL END) AS first_month_with_many_orders 
FROM monthly_orders
```

I need the first condition of number_of_orders >=10 to be evaluated first. This code doesn't seem to be accomplishing this because I have some companies that have month that meet both conditions so it returns the minimum month that meets the first condition. However, what I really want is the minimum month of month that >=10 orders and I only want the second condition to apply to companies that have no months with more than 10 orders.

So how can I get the first condition to be evaluated and then only move on to the second condition if it fails?

Comment: Is this about SQL-Server or another DBMS?

Comment: Both your conditions return `order_month` (the `THEN` clause).

Comment: Will you put in some dummy data and show us what is correct output from that?

Answer (score 0):

First, your SQL case returns `order_month` in both cases `number_of_orders >= 10` and `number_of_orders >= 1 AND number_of_orders < 10`. This might be wrong, not sure about.

Second, I recommend a subquery, something like this:

```
SELECT company_id, MIN(theSubquery.month_with_many_orders) as first_month_with_many_orders
FROM (
  SELECT company_id, 
         CASE WHEN number_of_orders >= 10 THEN order_month 
              WHEN number_of_orders >= 1 AND number_of_orders < 10 THEN order_month 
         ELSE NULL END) AS month_with_many_orders
) AS theSubquery
```

I am not sure about the correct details as no more information is provided. But usually, I make the experience that subqueries allow to make steps that are more clear. You could probably even get rid of the CASE and use WHERE in the subquery which would be even more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get what you have written:

- If the company has at least one month with 10 orders or more, you want the first month when this occurs
- If the first condition is not true for any month, you want the first month with at least 1 order
- Or else, you want null values for those companies that have no orders

If I am right, the SQL would be:

```
SELECT 
     company_id, 
     IsNull((SELECT MIN(order_month) FROM monthly_orders WHERE company_id = A.company_id and number_of_order >= 10),(SELECT MIN(order_month) FROM monthly_orders WHERE company_id = A.company_id and number_of_order >= 1 and number_of_order < 10))
FROM monthly_orders A
GROUP BY company_id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/22e51/3/0)

**UPDATE**

Another query would be

```
 SELECT 
    A.company_id,
    min(case when MAX_ORDER = 0 then NULL ELSE order_month END) first_month_with_many_orders 
 FROM monthly_orders A
 INNER JOIN (SELECT company_id, MAX(number_of_order) MAX_ORDER FROM monthly_orders GROUP BY company_id) as B
     ON A.company_id = B.company_id
     AND number_of_order >= (CASE WHEN MAX_ORDER >= 10 THEN 10 WHEN MAX_ORDER >=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 GROUP BY A.company_id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a848/12/0)